# Receiving data from url receives 400 response code when run on Android but not in Java

Tags: java, android, input, output, server

I have this method which works perfectly in Java:

```
public static void generateData(double lat, double lon) throws IOException {
    double southLat = lat - 0.02;
    double northLat = lat + 0.03;
    double westLon = lon - 0.1;
    double eastLon = lon + 0.1;
    String urlParameters = "<osm-script output=\"xml\" timeout=\"25\">"
            + " <!-- gather results -->"
            + "<union>"
            + " <query type=\"node\">"
            + " <has-kv k=\"highway\" regv=\"(trunk|primary|secondary|tertiary|trunk|residential)\"/>"
            +

            "  <bbox-query s=\""
            + southLat
            + "\" w=\""
            + westLon
            + "\" n=\"52.45517254183315\" e=\""
            + eastLon
            + "\"/>"
            + "</query>"
            + " <query type=\"way\">"
            + "<has-kv k=\"highway\" regv=\"(trunk|primary|secondary|tertiary|trunk|residential)\"/>"
            +

            "  <bbox-query s=\""
            + southLat
            + "\" w=\""
            + westLon
            + "\" n=\"52.45517254183315\" e=\""
            + eastLon
            + "\"/>"
            + "  </query>"
            + "  </union>"
            + "  <union>"
            + "   <item/>"
            + "  <recurse type=\"down\"/>"
            + "  </union>"
            + " <print mode=\"meta\" order=\"quadtile\"/>" +

            "</osm-script>";
    URL url = new URL("http://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter");
    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

    conn.setDoOutput(true);

    OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(
            conn.getOutputStream());

    writer.write(urlParameters);
    writer.flush();

    String line;
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            conn.getInputStream()));
    File file = new File("route.xml");
    BufferedWriter output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        output.write(line);
        output.newLine();
        System.out.println(line);
    }
    writer.close();
    reader.close();
    output.close();
}
```

When I run it, an xml file called route.xml is created and saved to my file system. I can open it and it is formed as I expected.

I am attempting to use this within an android application. The method above doesn't work as it returns a server code 400 (malformed). I had a look around stackoverflow and adapted the code to the below for android:

```
public void generateData(double lat, double lon) throws IOException {
    double southLat = lat - 0.02;
    double northLat = lat + 0.03;
    double westLon = lon - 0.1;
    double eastLon = lon + 0.1;
    String urlParameters = "<osm-script output=\"xml\" timeout=\"25\">"
            + " <!-- gather results -->"
            + "<union>"
            + " <query type=\"node\">"
            + " <has-kv k=\"highway\" regv=\"(trunk|primary|secondary|tertiary|trunk|residential)\"/>"
            +

            "  <bbox-query s=\""
            + southLat
            + "\" w=\""
            + westLon
            + "\" n=\"52.45517254183315\" e=\""
            + eastLon
            + "\"/>"
            + "</query>"
            + " <query type=\"way\">"
            + "<has-kv k=\"highway\" regv=\"(trunk|primary|secondary|tertiary|trunk|residential)\"/>"
            +

            "  <bbox-query s=\""
            + southLat
            + "\" w=\""
            + westLon
            + "\" n=\"52.45517254183315\" e=\""
            + eastLon
            + "\"/>"
            + "  </query>"
            + "  </union>"
            + "  <union>"
            + "   <item/>"
            + "  <recurse type=\"down\"/>"
            + "  </union>"
            + " <print mode=\"meta\" order=\"quadtile\"/>" +

            "</osm-script>";
    URL url = new URL("http://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter");
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setDoInput(false);
    conn.connect();
    int status = conn.getResponseCode();
    Log.e("ERROR CODE", ""+status);
    OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(
            conn.getOutputStream());
    // http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-download-fileimage-url-your-device
    writer.write(urlParameters);
    Log.e("Download", "started writing");

    writer.flush();

    String line;
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            conn.getInputStream()));
    Log.e("Download", "got the stream ");

    File file = new File(getApplication().getApplicationContext()
            .getFilesDir(), "route.xml");
    Log.e("Download", "Created a file to save");

    BufferedWriter output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        output.write(line);
        output.newLine();
        System.out.println(line);
    }
    writer.close();
    reader.close();
    output.close();
    System.out.println("reckon i wrote to file.");
}
```

This returns a 400 response code from the server. I don't understand this as I don't understand how it can be malformed if it works outside of android.

I would really appreciate any help.

edit: The stack trace when run on android is:

```
> `12-29 22:36:41.779: W/System.err(18702): java.net.ProtocolException: This protocol does not support input
12-29 22:36:41.781: W/System.err(18702):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:187)
12-29 22:36:41.781: W/System.err(18702):    at com.running.mattboyle.runnertoolbox.RunningMap.generateData(RunningMap.java:215)
12-29 22:36:41.782: W/System.err(18702):    at com.running.mattboyle.runnertoolbox.RunningMap$1.run(RunningMap.java:121)
12-29 22:36:41.782: W/System.err(18702):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
`
```

Comment: "The method above doesn't work for some reason" -- you may wish to explain what "doesn't work" means. "This returns a 400 response code from the server" -- `GET` requests don't have request bodies, so I am not surprised that this is not working. Beyond this, check on your server to see what more information you can glean. If it is not your server, use a proxy (e.g., Charles) to see what is different about the requests.

Comment: Updated it to explain better and modified my code a bit (the GET was something I added just before I uploaded).Thanks.

Comment: You command to conn.setDoInput(false); and want to get input stream?